# In R, how do I omit NA data in a data frame for only certain columns, I want to keep NA data in all columns except for the 8 shown in this na.omit

Tags: r, dataframe, na

The data set has 24 variables.

Here is the code that I have, it keeps just shrinking the columns to those 8 columns and omitting the other rows and columns, I just want the other rows omitted not the other columns:

```
injury.data=read.csv("C:/Users/jacob/Downloads/hwk3data.csv", 
                     stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

injury.data<-na.omit(injury.data[,c(7,13:16,22:24)])
```

I am expecting to just omit the NA rows from NA in those columns not NA in every column, and I would like to retain all other data in other columns not shrink it to just those columns.

Comment: Have you tried the function `drop_na` from dplyr? Should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are removing some columns before you discard the missing values in `na.omit(injury.data[,c(7,13:16,22:24)])`. Note that subsetting with `c(7,13:16,22:24)` does not "scope" the effect of `na.omit()` - it subsets the dataframe permanently.